# New to databases - does my ERD reflect good database design?

Tags: sqlite, erd

I'm making a database to hold data for a media player that I'm working on. Originally, I thought to use one table with the fields:

```
{filePath,artist,title,album,track_number,length,date,artworkUrl}
```

Since I'm trying to use good DB design techniques, I've now created a DB with three tables. One for the audio file itself, one for the artists, and one for the albums:

[image]

I'd really appreciate it if some more knowledgeable people could evaluate my design and, give me some pointers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) [primary keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) instead of artist or album names.  Doing this will improve the database design because currently a change in an artist's name would require updating each entry in your audio_files table for that particular artist.

You and I likely agree it would be strange for an artist to change their name, however they have a [penchant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_%28musician%29) for doing this.  Even beyond the infrequent artist name change, you are much more likely to encounter artist name changes due to user error.

Also, I noticed that you use the path_of_file as the primary key of the audio_files table.  Keep in mind that files may move for a variety of reasons, some of which may be out of the domain of control for your app.  You should consider how your database handles that.

---

To answer your follow up:

If you go with the unique key approach I recommend, updating the artist name would be straight forward:

```
UPDATE Artists
SET Artists.Artist_Name = 'New Name'
WHERE Artists.Artist_ID =
```

Updating the artist name in the design you propose would involve inserting a new record in the artist table, creating a subset of file paths with the old artist name, then updating each file path record to the new artist record, and finally deleting the old one.  Yuck!

Comment: Answers should not end with more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. I did not realize how hard it would be to change the tables if one of the primary keys needs to change. I do see what you mean about artists changing names. However, I would probably keep the name that was on previous albums unchanged and use the new name for new albums. That does make for  an interesting problem though. If you have the time to spare, could you provide me with a sample of an SQL statement that changes the artist name across tables. This example would assume that I used an integer for the artists table's PK.

Comment: You wording is a bit "wrong". The artist's name or the album name can be a "unique key" as well. You are probably referring to "surrogate keys" where you generate an artificial unique identifier to server as a primary key. Any combination of columns can be a "unique key", not only generated ones. But I do agree that using names for the  primary key is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mark Iannucci's comments, I'd recommend making `ArtistID` a field in `Files`, not `Albums`, to support soundtracks and other multi-artist collections.  You may retain an `AlbumArtistID` in the `Albums` table, if you think it would be valuable.

If you want to be really thorough, you could consider having several artist fields in `Files`: `ComposerID`, `PerformerID`, `OriginalArtistID`, `CollaboratingPerformerID`.  Fans of classical music may prefer to organize their music by composer than by who actually played for the recording in question, for example.

Of course a song may have more than two artists, so if you really want to be complete, you should have a `Performances` table to support a many-to-many relationship between `Artists` and `Files` - but I expect that would be over-engineering.  If that sounds complicated, you can instead have a separate record in the `Artists` table for each set of collaborators.  So instead of `PerfomerID` -> "Everlast" and `CollaboratingPerformerID` -> "Carlos Santana" you'd have `PerformerID` -> "Everlast with Carlos Santana".  However, this structure would make it difficult to generate a list of all tracks on which Santana contributed.

Comment: I upvoted the @Jon-of-All-Trades answer because it extends mine well.  Thank you for the contribution!